# How to raster area bounded by two functions?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

This code works normally:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% only for pdflatex
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,linestyle=curve](-2,-6)(6,6)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-4)(5.5,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psclip{%
    \psplot[linestyle=none]{0}{6.5}{x*(3-x)/2}}
\psplot[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=vlines]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\endpsclip
\psplot{0}{4.5}{x*(3-x)/2}}
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\rput[bl](1.8,1.2){$y=\dfrac{-x^2+3x}{2}$}
\rput[t](2,-3.1){$y=x^2-6x+6$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but the following code is not working:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% only for pdflatex
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,linestyle=curve](-2,-6)(6,6)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-4)(5.5,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psclip{%
    \psplot[linecolor=blue,]{-1}{5}{-1*x+2}}
    \psplot[fillstyle=hlines]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\endpsclip
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\rput[bl](1.5,1){$y=-x+2$}
\rput[t](2,-3.1){$y=x^2-6x+6$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: You should remove everything from the example code which is not important for the problem, e.g. the margin setting, `amsmath`, a lot of the PSTricks packages, `graphicx`

Comment: @Herbert: I do so since I hope while compiling not having error.

Comment: `linestyle=curve` should be `plotstyle=curve`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define an area which will then be clipped. The area is build with connecting the first point with the last one. For a line you simply get an area of zero, and from this area nothing can be clipped!

With `\psline(0,2)(5,-3)(0,-3)` I define a triangle. It is automatically a closed area becasue it draws a line from `(0,-3)` to `(0,2)`.
And from that area the curve with `{x*(x-6)+6}` is clipping a part which will be filled.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,plotstyle=curve](-2,-6)(6,6)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-4)(5.5,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psclip{\psline[linestyle=none](0,2)(5,-3)(0,-3)}
   \psplot[fillstyle=vlines]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\endpsclip
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](0,2)(5,-3)
\rput[bl](1.5,1){$y=-x+2$}
\rput[t](2,-3.1){$y=x^2-6x+6$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative you can calculate the intersectionpoints (needs package `pst-intersect`) and using `\pscustom`

```
%%\usepackage{pst-intersect} in the preamble
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-2,-6)(6,6)
\pssavepath[linewidth=1.5pt]{Curve}{\psplot{.5}{5}{x*(x-6)+6}}
\pssavepath[linewidth=1.5pt]{Line}{\psplot{0}{5}{-x+2}}
\psintersect[name=C]{Curve}{Line}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-4)(5.5,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pscustom[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.4]{%
  \psplot{\psGetNodeCenter{C1}C1.x}{\psGetNodeCenter{C2}C2.x}{x*(x-6)+6}%
}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

However, that one with `pst-intersect` works not with `xelatex`

Answer (score 3):

## Generic Template

Proposed features:

- functions are defined globally so you can change easily.
- intersection points are calculated at "runtime" as opposed to statically hard coded.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}


\def\f(#1){((#1)^2-6*(#1)+6)}
\def\g(#1){(2-(#1))}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,saveNodeCoors,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none](-1,-3.5)(6,4)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-.5,-3.5)(5.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pstInterFF{\f(x)}{\g(x)}{0}{A}
    \pstInterFF{\f(x)}{\g(x)}{5}{B}
    \pscustom*[linecolor=yellow!50]{%
        \psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\f(x)}
        \psplot{N-B.x}{N-A.x}{\g(x)}
        \closepath
    }
    \psset{linewidth=2pt,linecolor=cyan}
    \psplot{.5}{5}{\f(x)}
    \psplot{-.5}{5}{\g(x)}
    \uput[-90](*5 {\g(x)}){$y=-x+2$}
    \uput[45](*.7 {\f(x)}){$y=x^2-6x+6$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Statically hard-coded Version

Cons: you have to calculate the intersection points in advance by hands.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f{x^2-6*x+6}
\def\g{2-x}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-1,-3.5)(6,4)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-.5,-3.5)(5.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,hatchcolor=red,hatchsep=0.8pt]{\psplot{1}{4}{\f}\psplot{4}{1}{\g}}
    \psset{linewidth=2pt,linecolor=blue}
    \psplot{.5}{5}{\f}
    \psplot{-.5}{5}{\g}
    \uput[-90](*5 {\g}){$y=-x+2$}
    \uput[45](*.7 {\f}){$y=x^2-6x+6$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So happy, now I understand your code perfectly. :-) ; :-) ; :-)....